# How to get the value of the declared type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a silly question. Consider I have a declared `type` as this:

```js
type CardType = 'InformationCard'
```

Is there anyway to use CardType as value? Like:

```js
console.log(CardType)
```

Comment: No. Types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: It's not a silly question, but this is not possible. Type declarations don't exist during runtime, so the only way for you to get the value would be to assign it to a variable and log the variable. There's probably a ducplicate for this but I'm blind soo... :)

Comment: You can do the other way around https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGAnAJjAvDA5ASTAMxEQFt4oBLcAYSWUwCgoBPABwFMZqUAVF9jJtiDxwaQA

Comment: Sadly types don't exist at runtime, so assigning the value to a variable or a constant should be the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, types are not determined at runtime as TypeScript types are just used to add type saftey to JavaScript. The code is checked against its' expected type during linting, and discarded when the project is bundled into JavaScript. So this is not really possible with TypeScript.

Instead, you could create an object that has a "type" field, and then get the value based on the type;

```
const myCard = { cardType: "InformationCard" } 
console.log(myCard.cardType);
```